# Join MySQL tables with three foreign keys to same table

Tags: mysql

I want to select all the division details from division table. But I want the name_full of each head_user_id,assistant_1_user_id and assistant_2_user_id

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_mst` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name_full` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_with_initials` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `nic_no` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `dob` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `address1` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address2` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address3` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address4` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tele_no` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mob_no` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_personal` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `role_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `creator_user_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `active_user` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `emp_no1` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `emp_no2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unit_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `division_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email_official` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  KEY `fk_user_mst_title_mst` (`title_id`),
  KEY `fk_user_mst_role_mst1` (`role_id`),
  KEY `fk_user_mst_unit_mst1` (`unit_id`,`division_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

INSERT INTO `user_mst` (`user_id`, `name_full`, `name_with_initials`, `gender`, `nic_no`, `title_id`, `dob`, `address1`, `address2`, `address3`, `address4`, `tele_no`, `mob_no`, `email_personal`, `role_id`, `creator_user_id`, `active_user`, `emp_no1`, `emp_no2`, `unit_id`, `division_id`, `username`, `password`, `email_official`) VALUES
(2, 'dss', 'ddsf', 'm', '2353246565v', '12', '2012-03-12', 'ewtewt', 'ryery', 'ertert', 'wetwet', '325235325', '23523534523', 'fdrg@yahoo.com', '1', '1', 1, '', NULL, '1', '1', 'cde', '123', 'sasas@gmail.com'),
(3, 'wrwer', 'egrt', 'f', '2432544663', '12', '2012-03-26', 'erwerw', 'wetw', 'ewtwe', 'ewtw', '132435435', '1243345345', 'dfggdfg', '23', '1', 1, '12', '12', '12', '3', 'pas', '123', 'sdasda'),
(4, 'asd', 'asd', 'f', '5671234676V', '12', '2012-03-05', 'sdgdsgsd', 'sdgsdgds', 'rgwergwetg', 'ergry', '12141242145', '1242135346', 'prameeshas@yahoo.com', '1', '123567', 1, '1234', '123', '1', '1', 'abc', '234', 'prameeshas@yahoo.com');    

  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `division_mst` (
  `division_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `division_code` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `colour` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `head_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assistant_1_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assistant_2_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `main_division_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`division_id`),
  KEY `fk_division_mst_user_mst1` (`head_user_id`),
  KEY `fk_division_mst_user_mst2` (`assistant_1_user_id`),
  KEY `fk_division_mst_user_mst3` (`assistant_2_user_id`),
  KEY `fk_division_mst_main_division_mst1` (`main_division_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `division_mst` (`division_id`, `division_code`, `name`, `description`, `colour`, `head_user_id`, `assistant_1_user_id`, `assistant_2_user_id`, `main_division_id`) VALUES
('1', 'D001', 'Administration', 'tjrtujrt', 'pink', 1, 2, NULL, 1),
('2', 'D002\n', 'Human Resource\n', 'yjghkhk', 'red', 1, 3, 2, 1),
('3', 'D003', 'Marketing', 'jhghfg', 'green', 2, 1, 3, 2),
('4', 'D004', 'IT ', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
('5', 'D005', 'Accounting ', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: FYI it looks like your foreign keys were created incorrectly since normally when a foreign key has been created properly you'd see something like CONSTRAINT `blah_ibfk_` FOREIGN KEY (`blah_id`) REFERENCES `blah`(`id`)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @hsanders Yes. But I need the SELECT query. head_user_id, assistant_1_user_id and assistant_2_user_id all references to user_mst(user_id).

Comment: @AnuruddhalankaLiyanarachchi John Woo gave you the answer before I finished mine... My comment was more of an aside to be helpful.

Comment: @hsanders Thank you for your help ! But I didn't get the correct answer yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
    d.*, 
    u1.name_full AS head_user, 
    u2.name_full AS assistant1, 
    u3.name_full AS assistant2
from division_mst d 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN user_mst u1 ON d.head_user_id=u1.user_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN user_mst u2 ON d.assistant_1_user_id=u2.user_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN user_mst u3 ON d.assistant_2_user_id=u3.user_id
```

Comment: This Results null department details with null values for name_full  and name_full details with null department values.

Comment: I know. I updated my answer. Use the new code above. I had referenced u1 3 times, where I should have used u2 and u3 in the other joins.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SELECT  b.`name_full` head_user,
        c.`name_full` assistant_1,
        d.`name_full assistant_2
FROM    `division_mst` a
        INNER JOIN `user_mst` b
            ON a.`head_user_id` = b.`user_id`
        INNER JOIN `user_mst` c
            ON a.`assistant_1_user_id` = b.`user_id`
        INNER JOIN `user_mst` d
            ON a.`assistant_2_user_id` = b.`user_id`
```

Hope this helps.

By the way, you constraints should look like this

```
  CONSTRAINT `fk_division_mst_user_mst1` FOREIGN KEY (`head_user_id`) REFERENCES `user_mst`(user_id),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_division_mst_user_mst2` FOREIGN KEY (`assistant_1_user_id`) REFERENCES `user_mst`(user_id),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_division_mst_user_mst3` FOREIGN KEY (`assistant_2_user_id`) REFERENCES `user_mst`(user_id)
```

Comment: I cant get the department details

Comment: INNER JOIN won't work because they will end up excluding each other. I believe you have to use outer joins.

Comment: I think the 3 inner joins end up joining the intersects of each of the previous joins, so you will not get any results. You have to use outer to effectively UNION the result sets of each join.